# What do the sides of the movement dice in Runebound look like?

Tags: dice

I lost my movement dice from Runebound. So I am trying to figure out what is on the different sides so I can use a normal D6. Anyone have images of the different sides or can give me a list of what is on each side?

---

**Ok so based on the answers below the sides should be:**

1. Plain, Mountain, Road
2. Hills, Plains, Road
3. River, Forest
4. River, Road
5. Hills, Plains, Road
6. River, Swamp

Comment: Someone who made cards to replace the dice. http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/828004/replacing-the-movement-dice-with-cards

Comment: closeup view of dice (maybe there is enough here to map it to a traditional d6): http://boardgamegeek.com/image/199023/runebound-first-edition  http://community.fantasyflightgames.com/index.php?/topic/25791-runebound-2nd-edition-dice-movement-d10s/

Comment: Cool! I have tried it, but i missed a side and the orientation is important as well. Maybe I should post what I cam up with and you can check if you agree?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As previously mentioned, someone made [cards](http://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/80528/runebound-movement-cards) to replace the dice.

The following cards are in his deck: (Ignoring "city" he added to every card)

- 6x Road, Plains, Hills
- 3x Road, Plains, Mountain
- 3x Road, River
- 3x River, Forest
- 3x River, Swamp

So it's safe to say the following represent the face of the dice:

- Road, Plains, Hills
- Road, Plains, Hills
- Road, Plains, Mountain
- Road, River
- River, Forest
- River, Swamp

So you were correct.

---

If [these dice](http://store.fantasyflightgames.com/client/Products/ProdimageLg/VA05a.jpg) are all identical, they have the following faces:

```
            +-----------+
            |       Ro  |
            |          >|
            |  Ri       |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     Hi    |       Mo  |  Ro ^ Pl  |
|           | Rd       >|           |
|  Pl v Ro  |       Pl  |     Hi    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+
            |       Ri  |
            |          >|   Ro Road
            |  Fo       |   Ri River
            +-----------+   Hi Hills
            |       Ri  |   Mo Mountain
            |<          |   Fo Forest
            |  Sw       |   Sw Swamp
            +-----------+
```

`^`, `v`, `<` and `>` denotes the top edge of the face. The icons are already correctly placed within the square. This indicates which way they should be facing. e.g. The Swamp will appear in the top-left corner of the face, while the Forest will appear in the bottom-right corner.

Comment: +1 ok so it looks like there are the right amount of each item, just their relationship to each other (which side of die they on) can be incorrect. But thanks at least I now know hwo to use my D6 d:-)

Comment: @AquaAlex, See update.

Comment: AWESOME, I have now updated numbers to be correct. I have same fold of a D6 so matched it to the sides and it should now be perfect.

Comment: Refined a bit further.